# BaseLayerAndroid creating destroying log messages

Tags: android, logging, webview, message

I am using a web view within an activity. When i run my app on phone, i am able to see lot of (continous) log messages with Tag BaseLayerAndroid.

```
02-07 13:29:06.458: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Creating BaseLayerAndroid = 0x1a328b8
02-07 13:29:06.505: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Destroying BaseLayerAndroid = 0x1977130
02-07 13:29:06.560: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Creating BaseLayerAndroid = 0x197fa88
02-07 13:29:06.599: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Destroying BaseLayerAndroid = 0x1a328b8
02-07 13:29:06.653: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Creating BaseLayerAndroid = 0x199fbd0
02-07 13:29:06.685: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Destroying BaseLayerAndroid = 0x197fa88
02-07 13:29:06.755: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Creating BaseLayerAndroid = 0x1ba8018
02-07 13:29:06.786: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Destroying BaseLayerAndroid = 0x199fbd0
02-07 13:29:06.856: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Creating BaseLayerAndroid = 0x19c48d0
02-07 13:29:06.903: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Destroying BaseLayerAndroid = 0x1ba8018
02-07 13:29:06.966: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Creating BaseLayerAndroid = 0x1a20a90
02-07 13:29:07.021: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Destroying BaseLayerAndroid = 0x19c48d0
02-07 13:29:07.067: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Creating BaseLayerAndroid = 0x198e480
02-07 13:29:07.099: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Destroying BaseLayerAndroid = 0x1a20a90
02-07 13:29:07.169: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Creating BaseLayerAndroid = 0x1977140
02-07 13:29:07.216: D/BaseLayerAndroid(27721): Destroying BaseLayerAndroid = 0x198e480
```

My basic code is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.display);


        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progress.setActivated(true);
                progress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progress.setActivated(false);
                progress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                webview.loadUrl("some url");
            }
        }).start();
```

Even when i come out of my activity, showing webview, i keep recieving this log messages.
Can anyone help me analyse what these log messages are all about and why are they appearing at such a fast rate.

Comment: do you have android:debuggable="true" in your manifest?

Comment: could you add information regarding what phone did you run this on and what version of Android that it has?

Comment: phone: Motorola droid android:4.0.3

Comment: @Joe I (bounty owner) am running this on a Motorola Droid Bionic, with android 4.0.3, as well. Is this an OS bug, or something that I can fix in my application?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I ran into this problem earlier and posted this question here. Later i figured out, that this problem is specific to webviews. As the webview tries to display a dynamic webpage, the view keeps on changing continously and hence the messages. I think i should add this as the answer for this question.

Comment: @NeerajSharma that's great, but it doesn't help me get rid of the log entries - did you figure out how to fix the layer creation?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Do you see these log messages if you run it on an emulator running 4.03 also? Maybe you can try running it on an emulator with a different version of Android too to compare. I am suspecting that this might be Motorola-specific thing, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, also on a Droid Bionic running 4.0.3.  It continues even when the app is backgrounded.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I assume you want to debug and your LogCat is full of these entries, you can create a filter that will remove them. Create a new filter and set the by Message to "^(?!.*(BaseLayerAndroid)).*$" .

Comment: @Raanan that doesn't solve the problem though, its just a band-aid.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, I actually don't think you can "solve" the issue as you described it here, seems like an android version specific bug that makes all these logs... and they are just logs so... band-aid.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in a webview (phonegap).

What I found is that the log messages seem to be related to the blinking cursor of a focused textarea.

I have jquery running in the webview and if I do

> $('textarea').get(0).blur();

the log messages stop.

That code tells the textarea to stop being focused, and so the cursor stop blinking and so do the log messages (wich seem to flow at the same rate as the blinking of the cursor).

The messages stop also when tapping outside of the textarea, while tapping in the textarea restart the messages.

I know this is not a proper solution, but I hope it can be a hint in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. The problem is that te WebView which I am using is hidden behind an AdMob AdView, meaning I can't really know the HTML structure.